# Equation which has to be solved with logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I need some help how to solve these equations for $x$. I think I have to use logarithms but still not sure how to do it and would be really grateful if someone could explain me.

$x^2 \cdot 2^{x + 1} +2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}
 = x^2 \cdot 2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4} + 2^{x - 1}$

$(x^2 - 7x + 5)^{x^2-2x-15} = 1$

Comment: I have the feeling that any solution would be using non-elementary functions.  Where did these even come from?

Answer (score 7):

For the first on, put like terms together.

$x^2 \cdot 2^{x + 1} +2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}
 = x^2 \cdot 2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4} + 2^{x - 1}$

$x^2 \cdot 2^{x + 1}-x^2 \cdot 2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4} =2^{x - 1}-2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}$

$x^2(2^{x + 1}-2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4})= 2^{x - 1}-2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}$

If $2^{x + 1}-2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4}= 0$

Then $2^{x+1} = 2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4}$

$\log_2 2^{x+1} = \log_2 2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4}$

$x + 1 = |x -3| +4$

$x-3 = |x-3|$ which simply means $x \ge 3$.

But

$x^2(2^{x + 1}-2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4})= 0 = 2^{x - 1}-2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}$

So $2^{x - 1}= 2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}$

$\log_2 2^{x - 1}= \log_2 2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}$

$x - 1 = |x - 3| + 2$

$x - 3 = |x-3|$ so ... again $x \ge 3$ will be a solution.

So thats one set of solutions $x \in [3,\infty)$.

If $2^{x + 1}-2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4}\ne  0$ then $x < 3$ though then $|x - 3| = 3 -x$ and we have:

$x^2(2^{x + 1}-2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4})= 2^{x - 1}-2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}$

$x^2(2^{x + 1}-2^{3-x + 4})= 2^{x - 1}-2 ^{3-x + 2}$

$x^2(2^{x+1} - 2^{7-x}) = 2^{x-1}-2^{5-x}$

$x^2 = \frac{2^{x-1}-2^{5-x}}{2^{x+1} - 2^{7-x}}$

$x^2 = \frac{2^{x-1}-2^{5-x}}{2^2(2^{x-1} - 2^{5-x})}$

$x^2 = \frac{1}{2^2}=1/4$

$x = \pm \frac 12$

So $x \in \{\pm 1/4\} \cup [3, \infty)$.

====

Number 2 is .... a little clever.

If $b^c = 1$ then either

i) $c = 0$

ii) $b = 1$

iii) $b = -1$ and $c$ is an "even rational" (a rational number that when expressed as a ratio of two co-prime integers has a numerator divisible by two).

if i) $x^2 - 2x - 15 = 0$

$(x -5)(x+3) = 0$

so $x = 5$ or $x =- 3$

and we have $(x^2 - 7x + 5)^{x^2-2x-15} = (25 - 35 + 5)^{25-10 - 15} = (-5)^0 = 1$

or $(x^2 - 7x + 5)^{x^2-2x-15} = (9 + 21 + 5)^{9 + 6 - 15} = 35^0 = 1$

if ii)$x^2 - 7x + 5 = 1$

$x^2 - 7x + 4= 0$

$x = \frac{7\pm\sqrt{49 - 16}}{2}= \frac{7\pm\sqrt{33}}{2}$

if iii) $x^2 - 7x +5 = -1$

$x^2 -7x +6 = 0$

$(x - 1)(x - 6) = 0$

$x = 1, 6$

$1^2-2*1-15= -16$ is even and $6^2 - 2*6 - 15$ is odd.

So $(x^2 - 7x + 5)^{x^2-2x-15} = (1 - 7 + 5)^{1-2 - 15} = (-1)^{-16} = \frac 1{1^{16}} = 1$

[But  $(x^2 - 7x + 5)^{x^2-2x-15} = (36 - 42 + 5)^{36 - 12 -15} = (-1)^{9} = -1 \ne 1$ ]

====

All this is presuming we are only considering real numbers.

Comment: What was wrong with my edit?

Comment: Not sure how we could conclude that we can't get solutions in the form of $e^{2n\pi i}$

Comment: I realize this is agrevating but I assume with questions at this level, it is assumed we are working with real numbers.    I think it's the job of the more experienced mathematicians to recognize from context what the novices assume rather than to insist the novice live up to their standards.

Comment: iii) implies that $-1^\frac{1}{2}$ is something else than $-1^\frac{2}{4}$

Comment: 2/4 is not in proper numerator denominator form.  In proper form it does not have an even numerator.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: if

\begin{equation*}
  (x^2 - 7x + 5)^{\color{blue}{x^2 - 2x - 15}} = 1,
\end{equation*}

what do you think $\color{blue}{x^2 - 2x - 15}$ is equal to?

This is merely one of the three possibilities. For all of them, please check out [fleablood's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1976266/303632).

Comment: It could be anything if $x^2-7x +5 = 1$.....

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: LoL, referencing fleablood's answer to make yours simpler?  Good idea, as reading fleeblood's answer might take me a while...

Comment: If x^2-2x-15 is anything then x^2-7x+5 must be... If x^2-2x-15 is an even integer then x^2-7x+5 must be... If x^2-2x-15 = 0 then x^2-7x+5 must be...

Comment: This is a very good hint.  If $bottom^{top} = 1$ there are a few ways this can happen.  i) there is something top can be that will *always* make this true.  ii) there is something bottom can be that will always make this true iii) there is something bottom can be that will *often* make this true iv) if we are accepting complex numbers.... well, that opens a bit more maybe...

Comment: Although we need to watch out for $0^0$.... which happens if $x^2 - 7x + 5 = x^2 - 2x - 15 = 0$ which is ... never.

Answer (score 2):

1) Making $2^{x-1}=a$ and $2^{|x-3|+2}=b$ you have $$4ax^2+b=4bx^2+a\iff(4x^2-1)(a-b)=0$$ This gives $x=\frac 12$ and $x\ge3$

2) You have two independent possibilities $$x^2-7x+5=1\\x^2-2x-15=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2 \cdot 2^{x + 1} +2 ^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 2}
 = x^2 \cdot 2^{\lvert x - 3\rvert + 4} + 2^{x - 1}$$

Let us distinguish two cases, $x\ge3$ and $x\le3$, to get rid of the absolute value.

1. $x\ge3$:

$$x^2 \cdot 2^{x + 1} +2 ^{x-1}
 = x^2 \cdot 2^{x+1} + 2^{x - 1},$$ which is an identity !

2. $x\le3$:

$$x^2 \cdot 2^{x + 1} +2 ^{5-x}
 = x^2 \cdot 2^{7-x} + 2^{x - 1}$$
which we rewrite
$$\left(2x^2-\frac12\right)2^x=2^6\left(2x^2-\frac12\right)2^{-x},$$

so that $$x=\pm\frac12\text{ or }x=3.$$

---

$$(x^2 - 7x + 5)^{x^2-2x-15} = 1$$

$a^b=1$ when $a=1$ or $a=-1\land\text{even}(b)$ or $b=0$, so

$$a=0\to x=\frac{7\pm\sqrt33}2,$$ 
$$a=-1\to x=1\text{ or 6},$$ where $6$ must be rejected as it yields an odd exponent, and
$$b=0\to x=-3,5.$$

Answer (score 1):

For the second one you should check when 
$$x^2-2x-15=0$$ 
or $$x^2-7x+5=\pm 1$$
Also for $x^2-7x+5=- 1$ you have to chekc whether $x^2-2x-15$ is even

Answer (score 1):

For the first one write $a=x^2,b=2^{x-1},c={|x-3|+2}$ then you get 
$$4ab+c=4ac+b$$ or
$$b(4a-1)=c(4a-1)$$
Which means $4x^2=1$ or $2^{x-1}=2^{|x-3|+2}$

Comment: But this way I still don't get the exact values of x?

Comment: So from the first one $x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}$. From second one $x-1=|x-3|+2$ or $x-3=|x-3|$, so this one satisfy all $x-3\geq 0$